Create a release on branch X from branch Y
We have a two branches, one - the default - is for staging and we call it "develop" branch. The second - the production branch - is called "main".
When we develop a new feature, we create a local branch that is based on develop. That branch is then pushed to GitHub, where we first deploy it as a "preview" on Vercel (this is not that relevant, but just to explain our work process).
When the feature is tested, a PR is opened from the feature branch to the develop branch. When the PR is merged, we want to automatically create a new PR (merging develop into main) for release to production. Release would increment the number and create a release log. If multiple feature branches are merged into develop, the release PR is updated with the latest PR that is merged.
Here is the setup from my test-repo:
enter image description here
Here is the release-please.yml file.
name: Release Please

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
    types:
      - closed

permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  release-please:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Release Please
        uses: googleapis/release-please-action@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.ORG_GITHUB_WRITE_TOKEN }}
          target-branch: main
          config-file: release-please-config.json
          manifest-file: .release-please-manifest.json

Here is the config file for release-please:
{
  "packages": {
    ".": {
      "changelog-path": "CHANGELOG.md",
      "release-type": "node",
      "prerelease": false,
      "target-branch": "main",
      "include-v-in-tag": true,
      "pull-request-header": "Release {{version}}  ",
      "bump-minor-pre-major": true,
      "include-component-in-tag": false
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleapis/release-please/main/schemas/config.json",
  "changelog-sections": [
    {
      "section": "✨ Features",
      "type": "feat"
    },
    {
      "section": " Bugfixes",
      "type": "fix"
    },
    {
      "section": " Miscellaneous",
      "type": "chore"
    },
    {
      "section": " Miscellaneous",
      "type": "style"
    },
    {
      "section": "⬆️ Dependency updates",
      "type": "deps"
    },
    {
      "section": "♻️ OPS",
      "type": "ops"
    },
    {
      "section": "♻️ OPS",
      "type": "ci"
    },
    {
      "section": " Documentation",
      "type": "docs"
    }
  ]
}

I expect that the release PR will always check the main branch for the latest release status (version, etc), compare this with the source (which is develop) which should have new commits (minus the "release commit") because merge commit to main is never really shared with develop.
I do see that the action runs, it seems like it can fetch new commits from develop, but when it should create a new PR, it "does not see them" and the PR is skipped.
enter image description here
